# Huawei E3372h usb_modeswitch

Tags: modem, raspbian

I'd like to switch my Huawei E3372h-153 from HiLink/router-mode to Stick/modem-mode. I use a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) and the usb_modeswitch tool.

My command to switch the device:

```
usb_modeswitch -V 12d1 -v 12d1 -P 1f01 -p14dc
```

This is my output:

```
Look for target devices ...
 No devices in target mode or class found
Look for default devices ...
   product ID matched
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 010 on bus 001
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
     Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
  Serial No.: not provided
-------------------------
Warning: no switching method given. See documentation
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye!
```

lsusb output is same as before:

```
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

So I have to find out what's going wrong. I searched for "no switching method given", but I don't know what to do. usb_modeswtich --help returns this line, maybe I need to add this to my command?

```
 -H, --huawei-mode             apply a special procedure
```

So my new command:

```
usb_modeswitch -V 12d1 -v 12d1 -P 1f01 -p14dc -H -W
```

And my output:

```
Take all parameters from the command line


 * usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
 * Version 2.2.0 (C) Josua Dietze 2014
 * Based on libusb1/libusbx

 ! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor=  0x12d1
DefaultProduct= 0x14dc
TargetVendor=   0x12d1
TargetProduct=  0x1f01
HuaweiMode=1
NeedResponse=0

Look for target devices ...
  found USB ID 12d1:14dc
   vendor ID matched
  found USB ID 050d:705a
  found USB ID 0424:ec00
  found USB ID 0424:9514
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 No devices in target mode or class found
Look for default devices ...
  found USB ID 12d1:14dc
   vendor ID matched
   product ID matched
  found USB ID 050d:705a
  found USB ID 0424:ec00
  found USB ID 0424:9514
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 012 on bus 001
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
     Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
  Serial No.: not provided
-------------------------
Send old Huawei control message ...
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye!
```

Unfortunately, lsusb returns the same result:

```
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

Has anyone tips to switch the Huawei mode?

Comment: try instead `-H`     `-J`  for -J, --huawei-new-mode